celery container continuous restarts due to PRECONDITION_FAILED
celery container keeps shutting down every hour (the consumer_timeout I set in rabbitmq) with the following error:
amqp.exceptions.PreconditionFailed: (0, 0): (406) PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery acknowledgement on channel 1 timed out. Timeout value used: 3600000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc guide to learn more

When listing unacknowledged messages in rabbitmq, I find the following:
/$ rabbitmqctl list_queues name messages messages_ready messages_unacknowledged consumers
critical 5 0 5 2

Note: I'm using the same consumer_timeout in a test env, and it's not causing any restarts
